# How to make the File menu drop down on form load?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menustrip

How to make the File menu drop down on form load ?

I want to make the File Menu to drop down when the form is opened.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to call the [ShowDropDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.showdropdown%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method in the form_load: